# How to embed a video in a tile as a Web UI in Windows8 Application C#

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am currently developing an windows 8 application using C# and XAML. In the Grouped Item Page, I need to launch a video hosted on youtube.

The video needs to play in the tile, as an itenm.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to play a video in a tile.  Tile updates must go through the [predefined tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761491.aspx), and there is only the capability to display text and images in those templates.

I recently published a [blog post on working with live tiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/20/real-world-live-tiles-working-with-live-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx) that might also be helpful.